# show a default image if image field is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set a default image  if the image field is empty

```
foreach($row as $field=>$value)
{
    if ($field == 'image')
    {
        if($field == 'image') 
        {
            echo("<td><img class='player' src='$value' name = '$value'></td>");
        } 
        if ($field != 'image') 
        {
            echo("<td><img class='player' src='images/players/default.jpg' name = '$value'></td>");
        }

    }
    else if ($field == 'flagImage')
    {
        echo("<td><img class='country' src='$value' name = '$value'></td>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<td>$value</td>");
    }
}
```

this code is not working what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value for $fields?

Comment: Why this `if($field == 'image')` twice? Debug the code you will get the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What results are you getting?

Comment: **Please learn to write the code according to the Standard** https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#11-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `if ($field == 'image')` condition is `wrong` then you code enter into `else if ($field == 'flagImage')` condition. None of you condition goes into default

Simple use

```
foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
        if ($field == 'image') {
            echo("<td><img class='player' src='$value' name = '$value'></td>");
        } else if ($field == 'flagImage') {
            echo("<td><img class='country' src='$value' name = '$value'></td>");
        } else {
            echo("<td><img class='player' src='images/players/default.jpg' name = '$value'></td>");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

will this part of the code ever run?

```
 if ($field != 'image') {
            echo("<td><img class='player' src='images/players/default.jpg' name = '$value'></td>");
        }
```

I think what you may want to do is to rewrite the nested conditionals and point to $value instead of $field.

```
foreach($row as $field => $value) {
    if ($field == 'image') {
        if (isset($value)) {
            echo("<td><img class='player' src='$value' name = '$value'></td>");
        } else {
            echo("<td><img class='player' src='images/players/default.jpg' name = '$value'></td>");
        }
    } else if ($field == 'flagImage') {
        echo("<td><img class='country' src='$value' name = '$value'></td>");
    } else {
        echo("<td>$value</td>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
    switch($field){
       case "image":
         echo("<td><img class='player' src='$value' name = '$value'></td>");
         break;
       case "flagImage":
         echo("<td><img class='country' src='$value' name = '$value'></td>");
         break;
       default:
         echo("<td><img class='player' src='images/players/default.jpg' name = '$value'></td>");
    }
}
```